# Powershell script to parse an HTML file, store HTML table rows into an array, compare with another array and export the mismatches to a CSV?

Tags: html, arrays, powershell, csv, html-table

I would like to parse an HTML file which contains multiple HTML tables, store the values of a specific column of desired table into an array, and then compare that array with a static array. Any entries in the collected array that are not present in the static array would then be exported to a CSV file. Is this possible with PowerShell?

I have tried to grab the table data using the Powershell code below, but am getting stuck here. How do I make sure I am collecting from the correct table and specify which column to collect from?

```
$uri = "URLwithHTMLTables"
$data = Invoke-WebRequest $uri
$table = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table") | Select -first 1
$table | select -ExpandProperty innertext
```

Comment: you may want to look at the code posted here >>> `Extracting Tables from PowerShell’s Invoke-WebRequest | Precision Computing — https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2015/01/05/extracting-tables-from-powershells-invoke-webrequest/` <<<

Comment: This helped a ton! Was able to extract the table data. Now I need to figure out how to compare the column data to an array and export the extras to a CSV

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] ///// for the comparison, you can either iterate thru one collection and compare each item to see if it is in the other collection OR you can try using the `Compare-Object` cmdlet. most folks seem to prefer the 2nd of those ... [*grin*]